# Does Divine Bond still require activating the weapon's enhancements?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, paladin

A 9th level paladin activating his weapon's Divine Bond grants him +2 enhancement bonus to be used as he desired:

> These bonuses can be added to the weapon, stacking with existing weapon bonuses to a maximum of +5, or they can be used to add any of the following weapon properties: *axiomatic, brilliant energy, defending, disruption, flaming, flaming burst, holy, keen, merciful*, and *speed*. Adding these properties consumes an amount of bonus equal to the property's cost

If I choose to add *flaming burst*, my weapon gets (emphasis mine):

> A *flaming burst* weapon **functions as a *flaming* weapon** that also explodes with flame upon striking a successful critical hit. [...] **In addition to the extra fire damage from the *flaming* ability** [...], a *flaming burst* weapon deals an extra 1d10 points of fire damage on a successful critical hit. [...]
>
> Even **if the *flaming* ability is not active**, the weapon still deals its extra fire damage **on a successful critical hit**.

The way I interpret this, is that when I activate Divine Bond and choose *flaming burst*, I immediately gain the benefit of *flaming burst* (extra damage on crits). But the *flaming* ability still needs to be activated in order to gain its benefit (extra damage on regular hits).

But that seems clunky to me. Can someone tell me whether I will need to spend **another** standard action after Divine Bond to activate the *flaming* weapon ability?

Comment: [Related] [Can the Pathfinder Magus add the Flaming/Frost/Shock enchantments pre-activated?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73484)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Thanks! I noticed searching for related questions is a lot harder on the Stack Exchange mobile app. I don't have access to the desktop for a while. I'm confident I would've found that question if I used the desktop website.

Comment: No problem! It's the upside of collective curation that *someone* will probably find and mention it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, it is still required.**

The class feature adds the e.g. [Flaming](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/flaming/) property, and that property states that it needs to be activated as a command. Nothing in the text indicates that it works otherwise.

This is similar to the magus [Arcane Pool](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/#Arcane_Pool_Su) feature, and you can find some discussion about it [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73484/can-the-pathfinder-magus-add-the-flaming-frost-shock-enchantments-pre-activated).

Comment: Sucks but true, action economy is very bad for this.